# Elastic Search Query for Relevancy Given a Phrase Rather Than Just One Word

Tags: elasticsearch

***Elastic Search querying/boosting is not working as I would expect it to...***

**I have an index where documents look like this:**

```json
{
  "entity_id" : "x",
  "entity_name" : "y",
  "description": "search engine",
  "keywords" : [
    "Google"
  ]
}
```

**Im trying to get the document to show up with a relevancy score when querying by a search phrase that contains one of the keywords.
like this:**

```json
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "What are some of products for Google?",
          "boost": 10,
          "fields": ["keywords"]
        }
      }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "entity_name" : "y" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The problem is that my results are not as expected for three reasons:**

1. The result contains hits that do not have any relevancy to "Google" or "Products" or any words in the search phrase.
2. The document that I am expecting to get returned has a `_score` = 0.0
3. The document that I am expecting to get returned has a mysterious `"_ignored" : [ "description.keyword"],`

**The response looks like this:**

```json
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source": {
           "entity_id" : "a",
           "entity_name" : "y",
           "description": "some other entity",
           "keywords": ["Other"]
        }
      },
      {
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_ignored" : [
          "description.keyword"
        ],
        "_source": {

           "entity_id" : "x",
           "entity_name" : "y",
           "description": "search engine",
           "keywords": ["Google"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you done the index mapping yourself ? or kept the default values ? Could you maybe paste in your question the mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

You use the wrong query type, `query_string` is not suitable for your needs, maybe use `match`

## To understand

##### First and foremost:

`_ignored` is a field that track all the fields that where malformed at index time, and thus are going to be ignored at search time. [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ignored-field.html)

##### Why is my score `0`:

It is because of the `query_string` query. [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

> Returns documents based on a provided query string, using a parser with a strict syntax.
> eg:
>
> "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)"
>
> The query_string query splits (new york
> city) OR (big apple) into two parts: new york city and big apple.

To illustrate my point, look at the example bellow:

```json
POST /so_relevance_score/_doc
{
  "entity_id" : "x",
  "entity_name" : "y",
  "description": "search engine",
  "keywords" : [
    "Google"
  ]
}

POST /so_relevance_score/_doc
{
  "entity_id" : "x",
  "entity_name" : "y",
  "description": "consumer electronic",
  "keywords" : [
    "Apple"
  ]
}

GET /so_relevance_score/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "What are some of products for Google?",
          "boost": 10,
          "fields": ["keywords"]
        }
      }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "entity_name" : "y" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will return the following results:

```json
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "so_relevance_score",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0uYgP34Bpf2xEaYqLYai",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entity_id" : "x",
          "entity_name" : "y",
          "description" : "search engine",
          "keywords" : [
            "Google"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "so_relevance_score",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1eYmP34Bpf2xEaYquoZC",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entity_id" : "x",
          "entity_name" : "y",
          "description" : "consumer electronic",
          "keywords" : [
            "Apple"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Score is `0` for both document. Which means that both documents are as relevant on this query for `ElasticSearch`.

But if you were to change the query type to `match`

```json
GET /so_relevance_score/_search
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "match": {
          "keywords": "What are some of products for Google?"
        }
      }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "entity_name" : "y" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```json
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6931471,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "so_relevance_score",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "0uYgP34Bpf2xEaYqLYai",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "entity_id" : "x",
          "entity_name" : "y",
          "description" : "search engine",
          "keywords" : [
            "Google"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "so_relevance_score",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1eYmP34Bpf2xEaYquoZC",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "entity_id" : "x",
          "entity_name" : "y",
          "description" : "consumer electronic",
          "keywords" : [
            "Apple"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With a relevance score !

If you want to fine tune your results, I suggest diving into the documentation for query types [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for your insight. `description.keyword` is not a field in the index. So I dont know how that could be malformed. there is a description field and a keyword field, but after removing the entire index and rebuilding it ensuring that it is not malfomed, the same result comes back

Comment: Damm ... okay, have you had the time to get the mapping of the index it help to reproduce the issue

Comment: I created these records without a mapping.

Comment: Hey man, I hope the updated version helps